# Is the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture solved?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, open-problem

I read today that in 2010 Manjul Bhargava with Arul Shankar proved the conjecture basing upon the work of Kolyvagin. Is it right? Does it satisfy for all elliptic curves, or is it limited to some part? Can anyone tell the status of the conjecture?

The reference where I found this information is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birch_and_Swinnerton-Dyer_conjecture#Current_status).

Thanks a lot.

(I think intervention of some experts in Iwasawa theory is needed as it is about Iwasawa theory, I think that it will be nice if it is posted at MO.)

Comment: The article you link doesn't say anyone's claimed a proof of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer. It says there's a claimed proof that "a positive proportion of elliptic curves over Q" satisfy the conjecture.

Comment: Even the Wikipedia link does not assert they proved the entire conjecture; rather, that they only established that a "positive proportion of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$[...] satisfy the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture". That means that it holds for a nontrivial "amount" of elliptic curves, but not necessarily for all of them (e.g., a positive proportion of all rational primes are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$; that doesn't mean *all* rational primes are congruent to $1$ modulo $4$, nor that there are only finitely many exceptions).

Comment: @iyengar: I am not sure if posting your questions here is the best way to circumvent your suspension on Math Overflow.

Comment: but its said that the combined result of Kolyvagin proves it

Comment: I heard Bhargava repeat a joke auidience-question: Since he proved BSD holds for 10% of elliptic curves, shouldn't Clay offer him $100K? :-)

Comment: Iyengar: Please type more carefully. It is **really** not much to ask that you make an effort to have what you write minimally resemble the rest of the site. I did not downvote but given the complete absence of care with respect to spelling, capitalization and punctuation which you insistently display, I can imagine a few reasons why someone would think your post to be of bad quality.

Comment: but who is that black sheep downvoting unnecessarily ,i begged always to say the reason of downvotes(i dont mind downvoting ,but if you tell the reason i can rectify my self,but i surely suspect that some people in Stackexchange are having hidden grudge on me,i dont know whats the mistake i did),whats problem with the above question??,

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez:yes sir,but you see majority of my questions get downvoted without reason ,wont it annoy anybody in my place??

Comment: I have given you a perfectly reasonable reason for your question to be downvoted. Please do not use these comments to discuss this, as it is completely off-topic: if you feel you must, start a meta thread. Here this discussion only makes more noise.

Comment: @Srivatsan: I appreciate the effort you put in fixing the post, but Iyengar has asked about 30 questions already, and by now he should have picked up the fact that he should do that himself. Teach a man to fish and all.

Comment: @Mariano Yes, I agree with you, and it was with some guilt that I fixed the post for the OP. I hope the OP corrects the issue with his spelling and grammar soon; certainly I will not be around to fix the posts each time. And I do not quite intend to continue fixing iyengar's posts unless he shows more care in the future.

Comment: Dear Iyengar, You are misreading wikipedia: what is written is that, combining their work with that of Kolyvagin, one deduces that *a positive proportion* of elliptic curves satisfy BSD.  There is no claim about *all* curves.  Actually, though, as far as I can tell the wikipedia entry is incorrect in invoking Kolyvagin; this is not how Bhargava and Shankar argue.  (See my answer below.)  Regards,

Comment: The answer to the question in the title would seem to be "no". And to the question in the body of the post "If you know more than we do, claim your $1m". As it stands neither is really a proper question, and this ought to be closed - except that the comments are interesting.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bhargava and Shankar have proved results about average $3$-Selmer ranks of elliptic curves.  (See [this arxiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/1007.0052), which is
the same paper cited by the Wikipedia article linked in the OP.)  Their
argument is via geometry of numbers (so to speak).

In fact, they are able to construct families such that exactly half of them
have positive sign in their functional equation, and with average $3$-Selmer rank bounded by $7/6$. (This
can be achieved by imposing appropriate conditions on the coefficients of the
elliptic curve, and computing the root number as a product of local roots numbers.) Now
work of the Dokchitser brothers on the parity conjecture implies that for elliptic curves with sign $+1$, the rank of the $3$-Selmer group is even.  When combined with the
bound of $7/6$, they deduce that the $3$-Selmer groups of the curves with sign $+1$ that lie in their family must be trivial.

Now (under some additional assumptions about the $3$-torsion, and some other
technical assumptions, which they are able to impose on their family) by applying the results of Skinner and Urban on the Main Conjecture (which lets one pass from triviality of a Selmer group to non-vanishing of the $L$-function) they deduce that the curves in their family having sign $+1$ also have non-vanishing $L$-value at $s = 1$.

Now a positive proportion of elliptic curves overall lie in their family,
and so putting all this together, one finds that a positive proportion of elliptic curves have both $3$-Selmer rank zero (and in particular, Mordell--Weil rank zero) and also analytic rank zero.  Thus, a positive
proportion of elliptic curves satisfy (the rank part of) BSD.

From my brief reading of the paper, the work of Kolyvagin and Gross--Zagier is not actually used (at least explicitly); Wikipedia seems to be in error on this point.

Answer (score 7):

"Birch and Swinnerton Dyer conjecture" usually refers to an amazing formula that predicts exactly the leading term of the L-function at $s=1$ (a real number $c$ and an integer $k$ such that the leading term is $c(s-1)^k$).  The prediction of $k$ only, the conjecture that it is an "analytic rank" equal to the rank of the group of rational points on the curve, is the BSD *rank conjecture*.  The million dollar prize is for the full conjecture with both $c$ and $k$, but the rank conjecture is a celebrated problem in its own right.

The Bhargava-Shankar paper proves, among other things, that a positive fraction of elliptic curves satisfy the rank prediction of BSD.  In fact their ArXiv paper uses "BSD" to refer to the rank conjecture only.  This is a loose but not uncommon use of the term.

I don't think the full BSD conjecture with the exact prediction of the leading coefficient of the L-function, is known for more than a finite number of curves.

Comment: Dear zyx, Work of William Stein, Amod Agashe, and others, is pretty close to establishing, in the case when $L(E,1) \neq 0$, that the precise conjectured formula of BSD holds.  So I don't think one is too far from improving Bhargava and Shankar's result to getting the full BSD conjecture for the rank $0$ members of their family.  But you may well be right that at the moment one doesn't know full BSD for more than finitely many curves.   Regards,

Comment: As far as I know, the Million Dollar prize is for the rank part of the conjecture (not that it matters). Moreover, it is historically fairly accurate to refer to the rank part as "BSD". The precise conjecture on the leading coefficient was formulated by Tate. Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer had given a formulation for rank 0 curves (in which case we can talk about the _value_ instead of the leading coefficient), and had also indicated that in the case of positive rank, heights of the generators of the Mordell-Weil group seemed to play a role, but they never mentioned the regulator explicitly.

Comment: @Alex B,  thanks. About the leading coefficient,  Tate's paper on B-SD calls the refined conjecture, for positive rank and using the height pairing, "the second conjecture [i.e., from the second paper] of Birch and Swinnerton". The same story appears in Milne's notes on elliptic curves.  I thought Tate's contributions had to do with isogeny invariance, a formulation over function fields, and the generalization to Abelian varieties, but I don't know the history well at all.  Is there a good reference?

Comment: @Matt E, thanks for the information about the rank 0 case.

Comment: @xyz Yes, there is: the original papers of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer. It is very easy to convince oneself that they didn't have a precise expression for the leading coefficient for positive rank when they formulated the conjecture. In "Conjectures concerning elliptic curves", Proc. Symp. Pure Math. Vol. VIII, Birch explicitly credits Tate with the formulation we know today (penultimate paragraph).

Comment: @Alex: I'll have a look at that, but of what is available online: in the 75th birthday volume for Swinnerton-Dyer, Birch writes of the positive rank leading coefficient conjecture that the 1965 doctoral thesis of his student Nelson Stephens "is where it is first precisely stated". Stephens' 1966 paper "Conjectures concerning Elliptic Curves", taken from his thesis, formulates the precise conjecture (for twists of the Fermat cubic) in terms of heights and says "this is in essence a formula suggested by Tate and others, by analogy with the work of Ono [on Tamagawa numbers]."